# some select queries that use date format

Tags: mysql

So.. to return the age based on a date type it's really easy :
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DateofBirth) and we get a result set with the age of the person

> But what if I need to search the people with an age range of 60-70 in the table based on their date of birthdays in this format d/m/y ( Ex: 2005-04-11). I considered it was kind of hard because it's a different thing searching for an certain age if u have only dateofbirths instead of searching through a column where u already have their ages being counted as normal years ( 50, 60 etc )

Another problem that's not related to the one mentioned above:

> Let's say I have a table with Medics that has their names, surnames and their speciality.
>   We got 17 specialities : reumatologie, o.r.l, chirurgie   etc. and 108 doctors

How do I get the list of the medical specialities and the doctors that are in that range based on this format:

Ex: reumatologie - 4, o.r.l - 5, chirurgie - 10 etc

> 4 and 5 from the examples are the number of medics. I've tried concatenating and all sort of queries none of them worked properly though. Maybe will work with a case? if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, you can just do (not very good regarding performance though):

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DateofBirth) AS age
FROM tableX
WHERE (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DateofBirth)) BETWEEN 60 AND 70 ;
```

If you want performance, you can add an index on `DateofBirth` and use this version:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DateofBirth) AS age
FROM tableX
WHERE DateofBirth >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE())-70, 1) 
  AND DateofBirth < MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE())-60+1, 1) ;
```

Comment: Why are we doing `YEAR(x)-YEAR(y)` and not `x-y`?